# Microsoft wceload tool kills all running processes

Tags: windows-mobile, cab, windows-mobile-6.5

The tool that is placed in \Windows\ called **wceload.exe** kills all programs (some .NET program) except system ones (like Programs, Settings or FileExplorer) while installing a CAB file. The issue occurs on **Windows Mobile 6.5**, on **Windows Mobile 5.0** the tool behaves properly. Is there any patch or SP for the tool on that system? Have there been security issues regarded to produce this unstable behavior in the WM 6.5?